# Is it possible to give image instead of alert box?

Tags: javascript

I'm using `alert()` for javascript and would like to provide an image, i.e. `alert(img);` - where `img` is a variable for an image url.

Comment: No, you can’t `alert` an image. What you can do is show a positioned `<div>` on your own page. Since you’ve added jQuery as a tag, you can try jQuery UI, or one of several other toolkits or specific plugins designed to create dialogue boxes.

Comment: [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert) only takes a string, or an object to be converted to a string, as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom alert box. By default it is not possible.
For example you could look at http://bootboxjs.com which allow to show nice alert with Bootstrap style

Answer (score 0):

The alert box is a system object, and not subject to CSS. To do this style of thing you would need to create an HTML element and mimic the alert() functionality. The jQuery UI Modal box does a lot of the work for you, see [here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)